# Get the name of the parent folder in html

Tags: javascript, css, html, directory-structure

I am trying to create a maze of sorts on my website and want to save time by reusing the same index.html file since this maze is going to be 17,000 files.  How would I get the name of the parent folder? I would like to place the name in my heading, which is a `H1` element. Example:

```
/home/public_html/User/Home/Maze1/Maze2/index.html
```

I would like every `H1` in that folder to display **"Maze2"**

Comment: I made this function:
`var getparentfoldername = function() {var t = document.getElementsByTagName("script");t = t[t.length-1];var name = t.ownerDocument.documentURI.split("/");return name[name.length-2];}`
It seems to work for me. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your index.html to index.php. and add this line of code.

```
<h1><?php echo basename(__DIR__); ?></h1>
```

Comment: I was wondering why I got down voted at first... ha ha.

Comment: I downvoted you because this has nothing to do with javascript, html, css, or html5 which are the tags for the question. So it'd be confusing to someone searching those tags. Good solution though

Answer (score 1):

Using JavaScript. The below contains the script collection.

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
```

The executing script (the current) will always be in the last spot.

```
var currentUrl = scripts[scripts.length-1]
```

You can use the split function. Something like:

```
var folderLevels = currentUrl.split("/")
var parentFolder = folderLevels[folderLevels.length-2]
```

Then append it to the H1 you want.

```
document.getElementById("yourH1ID").innerHTML = parentFolder;
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a quick javascript for you that should make this easier:

```js
function getParentFolder(url) {
if ( !url ) url = window.location.href;
url = url.lastIndexOf('/') == (url.length -1) ? url.substr(0,url.length-1) : url.substr(0,url.lastIndexOf('/'));
return url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
}
document.write(getParentFolder("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/")+"<br/>");
document.write(getParentFolder("/home/public_html/USER/Home/Maze1/Maze2/index.html")+"<br/>");
```

Usage: `getParentFolder()` to return parent folder of current location.

`getParentFolder("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/")` will return `questions`
`getParentFolder("/home/public_html/USER/Home/Maze1/Maze2/index.html")` will return `Maze2`

Remember to include your javascripts from a common location instead of inlining them on every page, that would be a maintenance nightmare. :)